# IPv6 consistently slower on my network

Tags: networking, ipv6, bandwidth

This is more of a theoretical question than a practical one, but my ISP gives me a dynamic IPv4 address and a /56 IPv6 prefix. When running bandwidth checking tools, I see that I consistently get a 2-3 MBps lower values up/down (out of 500 MBits up/down).

This is consistent across all machines that I tested on my LAN (both Macs and Linux machines, wired, over good gigabit links). I tested different testing tools against different servers (public ones, and in various cloud providers). The router (USG) is not even close to sweating (as verified by checking the CPU usage in real time while running the tests).

The limit of 500 Mbits come from my subscription plan, I can order a lot more if I pay more without any hardware upgrade, and my own equipment should also handle a lot more (I did a trial on 1000/1000 and I got to about 800 MBps IIRC).

The latencies seem to be the same regardless of IPv4/IPv6.

So, out of curiosity (this is not a practical problem), what could be plausible reasons that I see this slight difference in network bandwidth?

Comment: Not knowing very much (facts) about the actual differences I can guess. The involved drivers are yet to be as "optimized" as those for v4, and maybe also "the overhead is larger".

Comment: Overhead due to larger would be a reasonable guess, then I guess it would boil down to how my ISP sets bandwidth limits. Tracepath reports MTU 1500 so the difference then is not trivial

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Comparison_with_IPv4 - barebones ipv6 doesn't seem to differ much (w.r.t. overhead), but add any options and the situation might change quite a bit.